# bash how to input * from a file

Tags: bash

The problem:
I have a simple compiler that compiles simple RPN expression. The compiler is invoked like this:

```
./compiler 1 2 3 + "*"
```

This works fine.

Now, let's say I've put

```
1 2 3 + "*"
```

into a file called input. Then when I invoke the compiler like this:

```
./compiler $(cat input)
```

My compiler will complain: unknown symbol: "*"

If I remove the double quote around *, the * gets expanded to file names. I've also tried '' and ``, no good.

So, how can I input a normal * from a file?

Comment: Try escaping double quotes like `\"`.

Comment: If he scapes the `*` like `\"*\"`, his program will receive `1 2 3 + "*"`, so the problem persists.

The solution probably will be something like, parsing on your program an unique argument, a string containing all your expresion.

`./compiler \"1 2 3 + *\"`

Or maybe, scaping the * character, and then, on your code, remove the quotes.

Comment: What does the 'compiler' do, can you make a basic script that still shows this problem ?

Comment: Removing the double quotes is the correct direction to fix the "compilers" problem but that will cause the shell to expand the glob instead. This isn't something that can be solved directly. You could use `xargs` to make this work (without quotes in the file) or similar though.

Comment: Though I usually discourage the use of `xargs`, you could do: `xargs ./compiler < input` (will work with the quotes in the file too). After all, that's exactly what `xargs` was designed for.

Comment: xargs works(with or without quotes).  gniourf_gniourf, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**zoo.sh** with content

```
#!/bin/bash
set -f
echo $@
```

**m.txt** with content:

```
1 2 3 + *
```

In a shell do:

```
set -f 

./zoo.sh 1 2 4 + *
1 2 4 + *

./zoo.sh $(cat m.txt)
1 2 3 + *
```

The shell is doing the expansion for you. This happens *before* the command runs. If you want it to stop you need to explicitly tell it. Read about it here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin

Above the script also sets this to prevent the echo inside the script to do the expansion and make this work as I imagine your code works. Your compiler probably does not (need) do this.

Remember to do a `set +f` to restore the filename expansion.

Comment: `echo $@`, without quotes, is exactly the same as `echo $*`. If you want to keep arguments together, you need `echo "$@"`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to remove quoting characters from a variable that contains them:

```
a='1 2 3 + "*"'
```

is with shell "quote removal". That is done every time a string is parsed by the shell (if it is not the result of some other expansion). So, this will not remove the quotes, even if un-quoted:

```
$ echo $a
1 2 3 + "*"
```

Even repeated, quotes will not be removed:

```
$ echo $(echo $( echo $a ) )
1 2 3 + "*"
```

But quotes will be removed if we re-parse the string with eval:

```
$ eval echo $a
1 2 3 + *
```

Or if the string is sent to an external program (not a builtin), it will be re-parsed on its return. That is what happens with xargs:

```
$ xargs <<<$a
1 2 3 + *
```

Now, for your specific case, either do:

```
$ eval echo $(<file.csv)
```

or

```
$ xargs <file.csv
```

In this case, xargs is executing a default echo, so is basically doing the same as above.

Please be aware that either commands work with this specific code, but are a source for serious security risks. Remember: eval is evil.